# select scss file based on env variable in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony5

Symfony 5.4 with webpack-encore

I have scss files in assets/apple1/partial/apple.scss and assets/apple2/partial/apple.scss file.
I have a env variable brand(The value will be apple1 or apple2 ) , How can I select the css based on the brand value.

I am using webpack-encore and loading app.scss like this:

`// enables Sass/SCSS support .addEntry('global', './assets/scss/app.scss') .enableSassLoader()`

so that I can use something like @import '$brand/partial/apple'; in the app.scss file

As an alternative ,How can i get env variable brand in webpack.config.js .So I can craete multiple app.scss file and add it based on env file.